# How do I make an SQL query that returns records only if there are multiple records for a date?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have a model that consists of company name and transaction date columns. Each row represents a single transaction.

How do I construct an SQL query that retrieves only those records for which there are multiple transactions for that company on the same date?

It should exclude any transactions if there is only one record for that company on that date.  Is this possible in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY company, date) cnt
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT *  FROM TRANSACTION_DETAILS
 WHERE (COMPANY_ID, TRUNC (TRANSACTION_TIME)) IN
          (  SELECT COMPANY_ID, TRUNC (TRANSACTION_TIME)
               FROM TRANSACTION_DETAILS
           GROUP BY COMPANY_ID, TRUNC (TRANSACTION_TIME)
             HAVING COUNT (*) > 1)
             order by COMPANY_ID,TRANSACTION_TIME
```

inner query finds the companies with more than one transaction a day.(multiple transactions for that company on the same date). outer query retrieves these transactions for the companies for those days only.

Comment: inner query finds the companies with more than one transaction a day.(multiple transactions for that company on the same date). outer query retrieves these transactions for the companies for those days only.

Answer (score 1):

use group by with `count()` function

```
SELECT company, date
    FROM t
group by company, date
having COUNT(*)>1
```

**Note: Here transaction date column must have to date data type if it is date time then it will need to convert date type**